# How do I add a column to a DataFrame that is a derivative of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry about a newbie question, I am making baby steps in Python. My `DataFrame` has a column `address` of type `object`. `address` has a `country`, like this: `{... "city": "...", "state": "...", "country": "..."}` . How do I add a column `country` that's derived from the column `address`?

Comment: Address is an object like this: {... "city": "...", "state": "...", "country": "..."}. I'll update.

Comment: df.dtypes says 'object'.

Comment: Do `df.head(2).to_dict()` and add output to the question.

Comment: Can't. Confidentiality. I'll try to reproduce tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry. I knew I shouldn't be asking a question late at night. Here is the sanitized `df.head(2).to_dict()` 

`{'address': {0: {'country': 'Spain', 'aaa': '333'},
                    1: {'country': 'Italy',    'aaa': '555'}}
}`

Comment: Okay, I think the provided solution works. Try the answer

Answer (score 1):

Without the data its difficult to answer, but if the values are Python dict, applying a pandas Series on rows should work:

```py
df['address'].apply(pd.Series)
```

You will have to assign the result back to the original dataframe, and if the values are JSON string, you may first want to convert it to dictionary using `json.loads`

**SAMPLE RUN:**

```py
>>> df
   x                                                     address
0  1  {'city': 'xyz', 'state': 'Massachusetts', 'country': 'US'}
1  2         {'city': 'ABC', 'state': 'LONDON', 'country': 'UK'}

>>> df.assign(country=df['address'].apply(pd.Series)['country'])
   x                                                     address country
0  1  {'city': 'xyz', 'state': 'Massachusetts', 'country': 'US'}      US
1  2         {'city': 'ABC', 'state': 'LONDON', 'country': 'UK'}      UK
```

Even better to use key directly along with `Series.str`:

```py
>>> df.assign(country=df['address'].str['country'])

   x                                                     address country
0  1  {'city': 'xyz', 'state': 'Massachusetts', 'country': 'US'}      US
1  2         {'city': 'ABC', 'state': 'LONDON', 'country': 'UK'}      UK
```

Comment: If it's a dict `pd.json_normalize` or `df['address'].str['country']` should be more efficient ;)

Comment: @mozway Oh, thank you for the suggestion. I didn't know that pandas Series.str allows to access dict value by key. Updated the answer. But will it return `NaN` or throw error if the key is not found?

Comment: @mozway NVM, it returns `None`

Comment: Wow, thank you! Is it equivalent to `df['country'] = df['address'].str['country']`?

Comment: @IrinaRapoport yes, it is